# Can't print log to the console

Tags: python, django, django-logging

I'm using logging in my Django project.

- If I set handlers to `file`, I can find logs in the file.
- If I set handlers to `console`, there is nothing happened.

Here is the setting

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'path/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'main': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
},
```

where is the problem?

### UPDATE

`main` is in my project since I can see the log in log file when set `file` handlers

And add one more information, I'm not debugging locally, I just deploy my django server with debug=true and access it through public ip

Comment: Just to be sure, can you add the whole `LOGGING` variable you set? Also, does the `main` module actually exist in your project?

Comment: Updated, thanks for your quick response

Comment: Are you sure you want `'disable_existing_loggers': True`? There's a warning against doing that [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#configuring-logging).

Comment: No this is just for debugging this issue